# How to remove LUKS encryption?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

I tried removing LUKS encryption on my home directory using the following command:

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/mapper/luks-3fd5-235-26-2625-2456f-4353fgdgd
```

But it gives me an error saying:

> Device /dev/mapper/luks-3fd5-235-26-2625-2456f-4353fgdgd is not a
>   valid LUKS device.

Puzzled, I tried the following:

```
cryptsetup status luks-3fd5-235-26-2625-2456f-4353fgdgd
```

And it says:

```
/dev/mapper/luks-3fd5-235-26-2625-2456f-4353fgdgd is active and is in use.
type: LUKS1
cipher: ...
```

It seems the encrypted device is active, but not valid. What could be wrong here?

Comment: WARNING the command op tried will wipe the volume if it its written correctly and there is only one passphrase. see `man cryptsetup` under `luksRemoveKey` the command revokes the password, at does not remove encryption.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### ANSWER FROM 2013 - See other answers for happy times

- Backup
- Reformat
- Restore

`cryptsetup luksRemoveKey` would only remove an encryption key if you had more than one. The encryption would still be there.

The Fedora [Installation_Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html#id994542) Section C.5.3 explains how `luksRemoveKey` works.

That it's "impossible" to remove the encryption while keeping the contents is just an educated guess. I base that on two things:

- Because the LUKS container has a filesystem or LVM or *whatever* on top of it, just removing the encryption layer would require knowledge of the *meaning* of the data stored on top of it, which simply is not available. Also, a requirement would be that overwriting a part of the LUKS volume with its decrypted counterpart, would not break the rest of the LUKS content, and I'm not sure if that can be done.
- Implementing it would solve a problem that is about as far away from the purpose of LUKS as you can get, and I find it very unlikely that someone would take the time to do that instead of something more "meaningful".

Comment: How did you know that? Any references?

Comment: Added reference to Fedora Installation Guide and why I believe backup-restore is the only option for going from full-disk-encryption to no-encryption.

Comment: this was probably correct when written - other answers more relevant now

Answer (score 22):

Removing key-slots is like forgetting a password, it has nothing to do with moving the replacing the LUKS device by the filesytem inside of it.

**You CAN non-destructively remove the LUKS encryption from a device, without having to backup, reformat and restore.** `cryptsetup` has supported this since version 1.5.0, released in 2012.

After succesful decryption of a LUKS device, the filesystem inside becomes available to the OS, and you can mount it directly.

**Warning:** This is dangerous, backup all your data first.

For LUKS1:

1. Boot from a USB key
2. Use

   ```
   cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt <device_path>
   ```

For LUKS2:

1. Boot from a USB key
2. Convert all key-slots to use LUKS1 compatible parameters with

   ```
   cryptsetup luksChangeKey  --pbkdf pbkdf2 <device_path>
   ```
3. Convert the LUKS2 device to a LUKS1 device using

   ```
   cryptsetup convert --type luks1 <device_path>
   ```
4. Perform the decryption using

   ```
   cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt <device_path>
   ```

I've tested both of these and they work.

---

Current versions of `cryptsetup` claim to support direct decryption of LUKS2
devices. The command is

```
cryptsetup --reencrypt --decrypt --header HEADER_FILE <device_path>
```

The `--header` argument is required, because the commands assumes your device uses a detached header. If you do, it works, and can even do the decryption online. If you don't use a detached header (quite common), and you try to either provide a dump of the header, or passing the block device itself as the `--header` value, `cryptsetup` will quietly proceed and when it finishes, you'll end up with a LUKS2 device which has no key-slots and your data will be gone.

This is as of version 2.3.3 (2020), it may change in future versions.

My recommendation is to use the safer LUKS2->LUKS1->Decrypt path, which I can confirm does the job.

Comment: This was fantastic. Thank you! I want to add a little.  After doing this on a CentOS system (RH probably similiar) you must take a few more steps to allow it to boot (assuming it was a boot partition). Boot from a Install Media, and Rescue the system. chroot in the system /mnt/sysroot.  remove /etc/crypttab. Edit /etc/default/grub and remove the luks portion.  Regenerate the grub config: grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg  Reinstall grub. yum reinstall grub2-efi (This part was a little tricky, without internet access, but there is a package repo on the recovery disk)

Comment: Note for me, after I did steps 2 and 3 above (under "for LUKS2") I had to reboot to avoid issues like this: `Attaching loopback device failed (loop device with autoclear flag is required)`

Comment: You may add to your post to use `lsblk --fs` to figure out what is the `<device_path>` to decrypt

Comment: How do I determine which LUKS version is in play?

Answer (score 17):

Firstly, when removing a passphrase from a LUKS partition, you need to specify the disk partition where it resides, like:

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda2
```

And when you want the status from a LUKS-encrypted device, you need to refer to the LUKS-name, as you did.

But luksRemoveKey only removes one of the passphrases (and never the last one). If you want to permanently decrypt, you have to use cryptsetup-reencrypt:

```
cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt /dev/sda2
```

Comment: FWIW, for LUKS 2 devices `cryptsetup` has a [reencrypt](https://manpath.be/f31/cryptsetup/2.2.2-1.fc31.x86_64/8/cryptsetup#L167) subcommand.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Chen She's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606231/472481), the default `cryptsetup` package with Ubuntu18.04 is 2.0.2 has a bug which exits the decryption command with return code 1, if the first active keyslot for Luksformatted device is not zero [(ref here)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1729600#c3) But it has been patched, as the next comment in the attached forum link mentions.

So, you might need to build from the [source from gitlab](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup) in order for it to work with your encrypted system.
Mind it, as of release 2.6.0 the command to decrypt a device has changed to `cryptsetup reencrypt <device-name> --decrypt`