# how to remove luks encryption from a usb stick

Tags: luks

I was looking at this thread to remove the encryption from the usb stick, but it says that the key cannot be removed if its the last.

[How to remove LUKS encryption?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60971/how-to-remove-luks-encryption)

I would simply want the usb stick to be a normal usb stick and not an encrypted one anymore.

Can a simple dd with null work?

I can create luksFormatted usb sticks, but how do I luksUnformat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only easy way to remove LUKS encryption is to back up the data on the storage device and reformat it to an unencrypted state.

`dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdX bs=8M` where X is the location of the USB device should work in your case.

If you prefer a GUI, then `gnome-disk-uility` (cmdline name = `gnome-disks`) has the tools you need.

Comment: sudo gnome-disks did the trick. I saw that one can also recreate a LUKS+Ext4 partition from gnome-disks.. dd was extremely slow ( dont know why ).

Comment: dd is slow because it's a steamroller that goes over the entire target device bit by bit, putting the bits from the source onto it.

Answer (score 1):

If you did

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdX
```

you can (destructively) reverse this operation by:

```
wipefs -a /dev/sdX
```

After that you can format it as any other vanilla USB stick.

Answer (score -1):

You can non-destructively decrypt your device without formatting it, or overwriting your data.
If you have an ext4 fs inside a LUKS encrypted partition, you can decrypt the partition so that the ext fs inside appears directly on the partition and can be mounted.

See my answer in [How to remove LUKS encryption?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60971/how-to-remove-luks-encryption/606231#606231). (I don't have the reputation to comment)

Comment: Why the downvote?