rhel 7.9 luks on lvm Cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt /path/to/device failing
Oh wise and powerful linux gurus, bless this humble wannabe linux admin with your knowledge!
I am attempting to remove the luks encryption on my rhel 7.9 device in order to facilitate upgrading to 8.10 (inherited device from previous admin with no documentation and do not wish to rebuild and lose its configs)
It does use lvm and best I can tell each of the 5 LV's within the Volume group are encryted with luks 1
/dev/mapper/rhel-00
/dev/mapper/rhel-01
/dev/mapper/rhel-03
/dev/mapper/rhel-04
/dev/mapper/rhel-05
Following the suggestions in the answer linked below I booted from a rhel 7.9 live cd into rescue environment, did not mount the host filesystem (went straight to shell), ran vgchange -ay vgname, and then executed cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt /path/to/device. This succeeded on each of them except /dev/mapper/rhel-00 which prompts for the passphrase, then returns to shell prompt with no errors nor progress.
cryptsetup status for the device just returns to shell prompt as well
cryptsetup luksDump does give output
I dont believe I am fatfingering the passphrase as it accepts it and does not give an error like it does when I intentionally enter a wrong one.
Ill update with information as needed but direction would help as I cannot easily pull data off at the moment.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606231
